# Does Dart Httpclient support self-specified tls connections?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a special flutter application，and want to set `httpclient`'s tls connection like in golang `DialTLS` or in android java `sslsocketfactory`

I found the document, which mentioned that `httpclient` can use `SecurityContext` as an argument, but I need to specify `httpclient` for tls connection.What should I do to set up httpclient's SecuritySocket

```
//golang
client := http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialTLS: func(network, addr string) (conn net.Conn, e error) {
                conf := &tls.Config{
                    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                    VerifyPeerCertificate: func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
                        return nil
                    },
                }
                fmt.Print(s)
                return tls.Dial("tcp", "", conf)

            },//This is the property I want to set in dart's httpclient
        },
    }
```